# Python docker sdk how to set cpu count in containers.run

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, containers, virtualization

I am using docker SDK for python 3 and running a container using

```
containers.run
```

We would like to set the number of CPU cores the container is getting and looked [here](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html)

There we saw there is a way to set the number of cores only under windows

How can you do it in Ubuntu via that sdk in Python?

If not at all, How can i control the container getting 1 core, 2 cores etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use `cpuset_cpus`

> cpuset_cpus (str) – CPUs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1).

so it looks like:

```
client.containers.run('alpine', cpuset_cpus="1")
```

Comment: So I am bound to use only 1-3 cores?

Comment: so what do they mean by 1-3?

Comment: what i understand from this is that you are only able to select a number between 1 and 3, meaning tha tyou can not use 4 cores

Comment: so you are saying that I can use 0 to core count - 1? Using more than the available cores will results with an error?